# Report is not getting generated even after configuring jest in pacakage.json

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, ui-automation

Report is not getting generated even after configuring jest in pacakage.json though tests are running without any error.

Attached screenshot for reference below:

[image: report-error-screenshot]

Sharing below pacakage.json code as well :

```
{
    "name": "automatedtests",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "MSL Test Automation framework",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --forceExit"
    },
    "author": "Deepak",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.4",
        "babel-jest": "^27.1.0",
        "jest": "^27.1.0",
        "jest-html-reporter": "^3.4.1",
        "jest-puppeteer": "^5.0.4",
        "puppeteer": "^10.2.0"
    },
    "jest": {
        "collectCoverage": false,
        "reporters": ["default", ["./node_modules/jest-html-reporter", {
            "pageTitle": "Test Report"
        }]]
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone can help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My package.json has the following: `"coverageReporters": ["lcov"]` and they're generated, not sure if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @alextrastero for the response but it's not working.

Comment: Also, the command I run is: `yarn test --coverage --watchAll=false` and then a folder coverage appears in my source folder which contains an index.html.

Comment: Hmm but its still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "name": "automatedtests",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "MSL Test Automation framework",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --forceExit"
    },
    "author": "Deepak",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.4",
        "babel-jest": "^27.1.0",
        "jest": "^27.1.0",
        "jest-html-reporter": "^3.4.1",
        "jest-puppeteer": "^5.0.4",
        "puppeteer": "^10.2.0"
    },
    "jest": {
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "reporters": ["default", ["./node_modules/jest-html-reporter", {
            "pageTitle": "Test Report"
        }]]
    } }
```